# How to debug a non-working conditional in Python?

Tags: python, variables

I am trying to establish a categorical variable with the Term column in my dataset.  I want RealEstate to = 1 if the Term is =< 240 and RealEstate to = 0 if the Term is > 240, but I keep getting an invalid syntax error.

[image]

Comment: Please include the code and traceback error as text and not as an image.  Please clarify what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Write it out on multiple lines. You gain nothing by golfing non-working code to the point that no one can read it to begin with.

Comment: (1) Show error messages and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or external link. (2) An if-expression always needs an "else". (3) The whole line of code doesn't look like useful Python. You should first work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet.

Comment: `RealEstate = 1 if Term <= 240 else 0`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], and [do not upload images of code or errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, copy and paste with appropriate [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). We [will not transcribe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040) images for you. Also, "Help please." is [not an answerable question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236).

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use `is` to make an assignment.  It doesn't work that way.

Comment: Anyway, there are multiple conceptual problems here. Please try to follow a Python tutorial and make sure you understand the fundamentals. For one thing, `is` is used only in comparisons, not to set values. `and` has a much more narrow meaning than it does in English, and if `Term` is a variable in your program that you want to check, it should not be quoted. `'Term'` means the literal text, an uppercase T followed by a lowercase e etc. - that cannot be compared to an integer.

Comment: Are you trying to assign a new column in a Pandas Dataframe based upon an existing column (rather than simply assigning a variable based on another variable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break down this statement:

```
RealEstate is 1 if 'Term' >= 240 and RealEstate is 0 if 'Term' <240
```

The overall construct you're trying to use here, called a ternary conditional, is `x if y else z`. The first problem is that you've constructed it as `(x if y) and (p if q)`.

As a basic operation, Python can't understand `x if y`, it can only understand `x if y else z` or:

```
if x:
    y
```

The second issue you have is a bit subtler, and with `is`. `RealEstate is 1` first evaluates the variable `RealEstate` and then the variable `1`. `1` is straightforward, and `RealEstate` could be an arbitrary value. If it is *not* equal to `1`, then this will evaluate as `True`. It won't *set* the value of `RealEstate` to `1`.

Finally, `'Term'` is a string and not a variable. It can't be compared with `240`, which is a number. So even if you fix the problems above, you'll run into this as well. You'll need to get the value of `'Term'` from somewhere as a variable that can be compared to `240`.

Comment: Nathaniel, thank you for breaking this down and helping me to understand the if errors with my code.  RealEstate is going to be a new variable that will split the Term (a column in my dataset) into a categorical variable; either 1 or 0 dependent upon the Term of the actual loan.